# Copilot for Visual Studio for Mac m1

Tags: apple-m1, visual-studio-mac, github-copilot

I am trying to install GitHub Copilot in Visual Studio for Mac as an extension. However, there is no option "Manage Extensions" in VS for Mac as shown [here](https://docs.github.com/en/copilot/getting-started-with-github-copilot/getting-started-with-github-copilot-in-visual-studio). [image: Extensions Panel in VS Mac]

Is it possible to add it somehow?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no Copilot support available for Visual Studio for Mac currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, As of now (Nov 2022) this feature is not yet released for **Visual Studio Mac**. You can also follow this [Github discussions](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/18691)

---

**UPDATE:**

[Microsoft just announced that they will be discontinuing Visual Studio for Mac in August of 2024.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-for-mac-retirement-announcement/)

[image]

Comment: Gotta wonder why Microsoft hasn't even put out an indication on their plans for extensions of VS on the Mac?